# Java applet shows a white square when in a .php file

Tags: java, php, applet

I developed an applet in Java for my website with Netbeans. However, while I can get it to work on a .html file, such thing does not work while inside a .php file...

I'm using Wamp server.

Is this a regular conflict between something, or is the problem in my code?
It simply looks like this:

```
<applet codebase="modules/progresso/applet/build/classes" code="progression/Progression.class" width=350 height=200></applet>
```

Comment: what do you see in java console

Comment: what do you see if you check the source of both pages in the browser?  does the PHP file generate the same HTML?  btw, tags such as "white" and "square" don't add much

Comment: Well, if I run it out of the browser, it simply works as it is supposed to :)
No errors.

Comment: Yes, when I check the source code, PHP generates the same HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're facing the problem with absolute and relative URLs.

Probably your PHP is in a different location and browser tries to fetch the `modules/progresso/applet/build/classes` from there.

Try to use absolute URLs (`/modules/progresso/applet/build/classes`)

Comment: Well, it gives an error but doesn't specify which one.
Just "There was an error while executing the application. Click "Details" for more information". When I do, it's just a blank screen :s

Comment: Does the applet code hide/ignore exception output?  What is the code?  Is the applet available at any place we can see it (broken or otherwise)?

Comment: I'm sorry, mr.Andrew, but I didn't understand what you meant with your 1st question (English is not my native language).

I uploaded the applet code to http://codeviewer.org/view/code:25eb
Do you also need the query and database access code? :)